# table just inserts one row. there is an auto increment id

Tags: php, mysql

This is my registration code.

Once I enter the fields in the form it shows me registration successful but adds blank data in my database table. It adds number 0 in my mobileno column.

Please help me here asap

```
include ('database_connection.php');

if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) {

$error = array();//Declare An Array to store any error message  

if (empty($_POST['mobileno'])) {//if no name has been supplied 
    $error[] = 'Please Enter a Mobile Number ';//add to array "error"
} else {
    $name = $_POST['mobileno'];//else assign it a variable
}
if (empty($_POST['fname'])) {//if no name has been supplied 
    $error[] = 'Please Enter a First name ';//add to array "error"
} else {
    $name = $_POST['fname'];//else assign it a variable
}
if (empty($_POST['lname'])) {//if no name has been supplied 
    $error[] = 'Please Enter a Last name ';//add to array "error"
} else {
    $name = $_POST['lname'];//else assign it a variable
}
if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $error[] = 'Please Enter your Email ';
} else {


    if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-    Z0-9\._-]+)+$/", $_POST['email'])) {
       //regular expression for email validation
        $Email = $_POST['email'];
    } else {
         $error[] = 'Your EMail Address is invalid  ';
    }


}


if (empty($_POST['passwd1'])) {
    $error[] = 'Please Enter Your Password ';
} else {
    $Password = $_POST['passwd1'];
}
if (empty($_POST['passwd2'])) {
    $error[] = 'Please Verify Your Password ';
} else {
    $Password = $_POST['passwd2'];
}

if (empty($error)) //send to Database if there's no error '

{ //If everything's OK...

    // Make sure the mobile no is available:
    $query_verify_mobileno = "SELECT * FROM userdtls WHERE mobileno = '$mobileno'";
    $result_verify_mobileno = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_verify_mobileno);
    if (!$result_verify_mobileno) 
    {//if the Query Failed ,similar to if($result_verify_mobileno==false)
        echo ' Database Error Occured ';
    }

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result_verify_mobileno) == 0) { // IF no previous user is using this number .


        // Create a unique  activation code:
       $activation = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));


        $query_insert_user = "INSERT INTO userdtls (`mobileno`, `pass`, `fname`, `lname`, `email`, `activation`) VALUES ( '$mobileno', '$passwd1', '$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$activation')";


        $result_insert_user = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_insert_user);
        if (!$result_insert_user) {
            echo 'Query Failed ';
        }

        if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) { //If the Insert Query was successfull.


            // Send the email:
          $message = " To activate your account, please click on this link:\n\n";
            $message .= WEBSITE_URL . '/activate.php?email=' . urlencode($Email) . "&key=$activation";
            mail($Email, 'Registration Confirmation', $message, 'From: rahul19dj@gmail.com'); 

            // Flush the buffered output.


            // Finish the page:
            echo '<div class="success">Thank you for registering! A confirmation email has been sent to '.$email.' Please click on the Activation Link to Activate your account </div>';


        } else { // If it did not run OK.
            echo '<div class="errormsgbox">You could not be registered due to a system error. We apologize for any inconvenience.</div>';
        }

    } else { // The mobile number is not available.
        echo '<div class="errormsgbox" >That mobile number has already been registered.</div>';
    }

} else {//If the "error" array contains error msg , display them



 echo '<div class="errormsgbox"> <ol>';
    foreach ($error as $key => $values) {

        echo '  <li>'.$values.'</li>';



    }
    echo '</ol></div>';

}

mysqli_close($dbc);//Close the DB Connection

} // End of the main Submit conditional.
```

Comment: Have you tried to see **actual** values for the passed variables? Why do you think they contain anything?

Comment: I am getting stuck here... I got the number insertion right but the issue is only one row gets inserted. After the first row it gives error of not getting inserted.

Comment: it is a good idea to always show the **exact error message**. Because your explanation "it gives error of not getting inserted" -- makes no sense

Comment: @zerkms When I register with the first data it inserts the data in the database and when I try to register again with different data it gives an error of Query Failed

Comment: "Query Failed" --- isn't a error as well. It is some arbitrary message your code returns, but not an actual error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning all of your variables, except `$email` to `$name` overwriting each one in succession. This is definitely going to cause strange results which are dependant on the data types of each column in your dataase. If `mobileno` is set to be an `int` has a default value of `0` a string or empty value will result in you seeing 0 in your dataase.

Comment: I did change to $name still the same outcome

Comment: i got it but the mobile no displays random number and not the number which was inputed

Comment: I am getting stuck here... I got the number insertion right but the issue is only one row gets inserted. After the first row it gives error of not getting inserted.